# How many products are allowed in Community?

Tags: product, magento-community

Magento is increasing price for EE every year, now we are thinking of moving to CE from EE (not my idea).

While looking at the features that we are using in EE, I can easily compare with CE. I can also see those extensions are available in market for CE.

However when in terms of catalog, it's hard to tell. Nowhere, I could find **how many products are allowed in CE**. Also how many attributes can I add to CE?

Everyone is saying- *not large amount of catalog are allowed in CE.*

Anyone could clarify on this for me?

Also what are the pros and cons am I looking while moving to CE from EE? I know it's very broad to answer, but would like to hear few important points.

Answer (score 2):

To get an idea bout what features you have in EE and dont have in CE check this awesome video from meet magento:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jrxq8EH5jUU

Regarding how many products and how many attributes you can have, I can't quote any source describing limits but I've seen stores handling over 1 million skus and 5 store views. Is possible but certainly you will have to optimize a lot of things.

Check this post for some very nice ideas:

http://fbrnc.net/blog/2015/10/super-scaling-magento

Finally a similar question was made before check this post if you have not already:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3654/5913

Answer (score 2):

There is no products limit in CE, nor attributes, or store views... the only limit is the one you have in hosting resources and/or code optimization