# Magento Upgrade from EE 1.10.1.1 to 1.13.0.2

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Magento version from `EE 1.10.1.1` to `1.13.0.2`. I took old DB and imported it into my development environment, I mapped that DB with `1.13.0.2` code base.

Then I tried to access the environment through the browser, it took many hours (more then 10 hours) and still loading. But the DB table import was reflected in it 3 hours. Now there is no  DB changes also.

Can anyone kindly guide me, how to resolve or track the issue.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/batching-database-schema-changes-during-upgrades/3274#3274

Comment: Login to MySQL and show processlist; You will be able to see if there are any items looping. I have experience credit that have increment_id's that include a DASH like 100023-23 will cause your upgrade to fail

Comment: Are you following the recommended upgrade procedure as set out by Magento?

Answer (score 2):

one Client had same issue, but his estimated time was 34 hours.(Quite large DB)
It took few weeks to adjust the script to minimize upgrade time.
Did not test it against 1.13 but it worked all the way up to 1.12.

Source is available at Github: https://github.com/magento-ecg/Magento-Upgrade-Replay

You can ask me for help.

Comment: Kirill, thanks for ur post. 
This script mentioned Magento 1.6+ (1.11 EE) as sys Requrement. But I want to upgrade from EE 1.10.1.1 to 1.13.0.2. will its helps me.

Comment: "Magento 1.6+ (1.11 EE)" stands for Magento 1.6+ or 1.11+ as a target version. There was only 1.11 when it was originally written but it worked for 1.12. You'd better try